# L'uso della preposizione "a" è facoltativo in queste frasi?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

"Siamo tre metri sopra il cielo" o "siamo a tre metri sopra il cielo".

"Oggetto ritrovato 3 metri sotto terra" o "oggetto ritrovato a 3 metri sotto terra".

"Abita tre metri sopra di me" o "abita a 3 metri sopra di me".

Sento spesso in giro entrambe le versioni, ma non so se il fatto di omettere la preposizione "a" sia corretto.

Mi dareste una mano per capire?

Comment: Così, a naso, con una specificazione “sotto/sopra”, il complemento di luogo non richiede un'altra preposizione; ci vuole in “siamo a tremila metri di altitudine”

Comment: Il testo è molto tecnico ma, se ho capito bene quello che si spiega [qui](http://lear.unive.it/jspui/bitstream/11707/305/2/ChoTesi.pdf) (la parte più relevante si trova alle pagine 189-190), @egreg ha ragione e sono corrette entrambe le forme, con e senza la preposizione "a".

Comment: A pagina 190 della tesi di dottorato che ho messo nel link del mio commento precedente si legge l'esempio «Si trova (a) due metri sotto il livello del mare», nel quale la preposizione "a" tra parentesi indica che è facoltativa.

Comment: In parole semplici e in modo molto simplificato questa pagina spiega che in italiano non si mette la preposizione "a" in frasi come "I libri sono sotto il tavolo", con un complemento avverbiale introdotto da preposizioni con valore avverbiale quali "davanti", "dietro", "dentro", "fuori", "sopra", "sotto", ecc. Però quando si aggiunge quello che viene chiamato un "sintagma mensurale", come accade nell'esempio del commento precedente, allora la preposizione "a" può essere presente in modo facoltativo.